# How to create a reset button which asks if you are sure to reset

Tags: javascript, forms, reset

I would like to create a reset button which confirms the reset it doesn't seem to work.

```js
function clear() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to reset the form?")) {
    document.getElementById("form-main").reset();
  } else {
    alert("You are safe!");
  }
navigator.vibrate([500,500,500,1000,500,500,500]);
}
```

```html
<form id="form-main"></form>
<button type="button" id="reset" onclick="clear();">Reset info</button>
```

Can you please tell me where am I going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: By properly indenting the code and using whitespace instead of stuffing everything together into an unreadable mess, we can clearly see that your JS code is missing the closing brace at the end. If that isn't just a copy and paste error.

Comment: Yes I actually have a `navigator.vibrate` function below so I forgot to copy that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your function name is `clear()`. It calls the deprecated `document.clear()`

```js
console.log(document.clear)
```

So, change the function name to something else.

```js
function clearForm() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to reset the form?")) {
    document.getElementById("form-main").reset();
  } else {
    alert("You are safe!");
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form-main"><input type="text"></form>
<button type="button" id="reset" onclick="clearForm();">Reset info</button>
```

P.S: Please use [addEventListeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) rather than using inline event handlers

Answer (score 2):

You didn't close the last `}`

```js
document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', clearForm);

function clearForm() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to reset the form?")) {
    document.getElementById("form-main").reset();
  } else {
    alert("You are safe!");
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form-main">
  <input type='text'>
</form>
<button type="button" id="reset">Reset info</button>
```

Instead of use `onclick` function i suggest you to use `addEventListener`

Good question:

-[addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Comment: If you're sure it's just the missing brace, this question shouldn't be answered but marked as typo.

Comment: Normally yes, but I wanted to add value to the question by specifying the use addEventListener instead of onclick

Comment: Obviously if it's wrong, I will delete and close question.

Comment: It works but now the my form won't reset.

Comment: @naveen answer will open our eyes :)

Comment: why the negative vote? This is also a very likely answer. The code was unindented and there was every chance that OP might have missed a brace

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with the `id="reset"` it was messing with the function `reset()`.

```js
function clearForm() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to reset the form?")) {
    document.getElementById("form-main").reset();
  } else {
    alert("You are safe!");
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form-main"><input type="text"></form>
<button type="button" id="resets" onclick="clearForm();">Reset info</button>
```